# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. List of apks

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run my app on Android Studio 4.0.1 It returns an error while installing the app on the phone

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to install-write all apks'
```

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode with allow installing of apps via usb?

Comment: Yes, Its on and USB debugging on

Comment: Do you have enough space on your phone to install the app?

Comment: Yes, I have enough space

Comment: does your phone have another App with the same packagename . Or do you have another version of this application installed? if yes try again after uninstalling it

Comment: Yes, this worked, but I don't know why, it should have updated the app.

Comment: Worked when I disabled  USB Debugging and enabling it again

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding `android:installLocation="auto` to the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="auto">
```